# Module not found: Can't resolve './Header' in 'D:\React-Taiga\taiga\src\stories\Header' src/stories/Header/Header.stories.tsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-typescript

What I alway get this error , seem my directory is correct.
This is my directory[image]

Here is my Header.stories.tsx code

```
import React from "react";
import { Meta, Story } from "@storybook/react";

import Header from "./Header";

export default {
  title: "stories/Header",
  component: Header,
} as Meta;

const Template: Story = (args) => <Header label={""} {...args} />;

export const HeaderStory = Template.bind({});
HeaderStory.storyName = "Top Header";
HeaderStory.args = {};
```

Here my Header.tsx code

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
import "./header.css";

interface HeaderOptions {
  label: string;
}

const Header = ({ label, ...props }: HeaderOptions) => (
  <>
    <div>Hi</div>
  </>
);

export default memo(Header);
```